# Map a nullable entity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, automapper

I am trying to map an id to object with AutoMapper and I have been trying to figure this out for two days.  Any help would be appreciated.

Here are my domain objects:

```
public class Entity
{
    public virtual Guid Id { get; protected set; }
}

public class Customer : Entity
{
    public virtual User SalesPerson { get; set; }
}

public class User : Entity
{
    public virtual string Email { get; set; }
}
```

Here is the edit model I'm using.  Sales Person is a drop-down list of users with a "None" option (`value=""`) as a customer may not have a sales person.

```
public class CustomerEditModel
{
    [DisplayName("Sales Person")]
    public Guid? SalesPerson { get; set; }
}
```

And here is where I am stuck.  These are the mappings I have tried so far to map the edit model back to domain model:

```
cfg.CreateMap<CustomerEditModel, Customer>()
    .ForMember(d => d.SalesPerson, o => o.ResolveUsing<EntityResolver<User>>().FromMember(s => s.SalesPerson));

cfg.CreateMap<CustomerEditModel, Customer>()
    .ForMember(d => d.SalesPerson, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SalesPerson.HasValue ? s.SalesPerson.Value : null);

cfg.CreateMap<CustomerEditModel, Customer>()
    .ForMember(d => d.SalesPerson, o => o.MapFrom(s => s.SalesPerson != null ? s.SalesPerson : null));

public class EntityResolver<T> : ValueResolver<Guid, T>
    where T : Entity
{
    protected override T ResolveCore(Guid source)
    {
        return session.Get<T>(source, LockMode.None);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the following changes and things appear to be working as expected.

```
public class EntityResolver<id, entity> : ValueResolver<id, entity>
    where entity : Entity
{
    protected override entity ResolveCore(id source)
    {
        if (source != null)
            return session.Get<entity>(source, LockMode.None);
        else
            return null;
    }
}
```

...

```
cfg.CreateMap<CustomerEditModel, Customer>()
    .ForMember(d => d.SalesPerson, o => o.ResolveUsing<EntityResolver<Guid?, User>>().FromMember(s => s.SalesPerson));
```

Comment: You could also use a type converter for that as well:

Mapper.CreateMap<Guid?, User>.ConvertUsing<EntityConverter<Guid?, User>>();

Where the EntityConverter is an ITypeConverter, looking almost exactly the same as you have above.